# Is it easy to shorten (cut) this ABS pipe and if yes, how?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, tools, cutting, saw

I have an ABS standpipe coming out of the wall for the washer drain. I’d like to insert a wye (for condensate pump) and ideally I’d like to shorten the pipe such that the total length remains the same.

I have never cut an ABS pipe and if it would just be an unattached piece of pipe, I wouldn’t be concerned: I would use my sawzall, I had enough room to do it and I wouldn’t need to be afraid that vibrations or movements knock the thing out of the wall.

Here is a picture (right the pipe, left the wye I want to attach):

[image]

Is it reasonably “simple” to cut off a piece of this pipe?
Or would you recommend by all means not to touch it?

And if shorten, what is the best way (approach and tool)?

Comment: You could just strap the condensate line to the laundry hose and shove them both in the top of the existing pipe.  Added benefit, the condensate won't slowly turn the outside end of the laundry hose into a moldy mess.

Comment: Hopefully that outlet has a GFCI outlet or breaker upstream.

Comment: It is easy to cut with most types of cutting blades.  The hard part is getting a nice decent square cut when adding a wye/other pipe connection.

Comment: ABS is soft plastic and easy to cut. But it is not advisable to cut the unsupported end of a pipe with power tools. If you have a sawzall, you probably have a blade for it with reasonable length and fine teeth, perhaps intended for metal cutting. That blade can be used to cut the pipe by hand. You can wrap tape around one end to make it more comfortable to hold. There is no great precision needed for what you're doing, just eyeballing it will be sufficient. Such methods to cut plastic pipe in close quarters are standard in the trades.

Comment: @jay613 hmm, knowing this earlier would have saved me quite some material cost ;-) The wye still feels more "elegant" to me. Why can't I just attach additional 1-2" ABS (from the piece I cut out, for example) on the top so that the condensate will never drip onto the end of the laundry hose?

Comment: @Huesmann Not as of now, but I'll replace with a GFCI outlet. Would such a dedicated washer outlet require (C)AFCI? I hope not. (Even if yes, I would need to ignore this one. I used a GFCI/CAFCI dual Siemens breaker before and the AFCI always tripped multiple times)

Comment: As you learn and do more DIY, you'll eventually realize the "elegance" is false, and then, at some point, it will even begin to bother you.   A Y is meant to create an opening where there isn't one.  Since you have a big open hole you should maximize its value to you.     And yes, raising the ABS pipe so the end of the laundry hose is above the Y will prevent the outside of the hose from being wet all the time.  It's not that important but if you ever have to service it you'll appreciate that it isn't disgusting on the outside.

Comment: I own a (big-box brand) hand saw designed for cutting PVC pipe.  It's a faster and easier to control than cutting PVC with a wood saw.  I would guess it would work similarly with ABS but I'm not certain.

Comment: @jay613 good points to keep in mind. For now, it seems the best approach is to add 1-2” of ABS on top the the wye and then cut the existing pipe such that the total stack is not more than 30” from the floor

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is the bottom of that pipe attached to the elbow that appears to go through the wall?

Comment: @divB yes, GFCI is required for laundry areas.

Comment: @Huesmann thanks for confirming. I just replaced it with an GFCI outlet. It seems now also AFCI is required but how on earth can this be? If I plug my washer into the CAFCI Siemens breaker, it reproducibly trips when the motor starts to spin

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't think you're required to retrofit AFCI if your house wasn't originally built with it, i.e. it wasn't required when your house was built (unless you had some major remodeling or something).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it can be cut.

My first choice, tool wise, would be to use an oscillating multitool. They're easy to control and you'd get a nice clean cut.

[image: DeWalt oscillating tool]

Comment: almost magic compared to a sawzall

Comment: Awesome! I have one. Is there a specific blade you would recommend?

Comment: @divB The ABS will cut pretty easy, any wood or even bi-metal blade would work.

Comment: And it doesnt need to be sharp to work either. You basically melt through it by friction. Can confirm this works, did this a lot in my house recently.

Answer (score 8):

As Matt said, a multi-tool would be the most available/re-usable tool for this. An inside pipe cutter would give a nice square cut.

[image: Inside pvc pipe cutter]

The second question is should you.

1. Look to the manufacturer of the appliance to determine minimum height of the stack. Since you might change appliances in the future, I would go with the standard height for your area.
2. Check local and plumbing codes.
   https://www.nachi.org/gallery/piping/standpipe-for-a-clothes-washer has a picture (which I can't copy here without permission) showing typical requirements.
   GE example of manufacturer specs: https://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-support-search-content?contentId=18682

Comment: (which I can't copy here without permission) : you have the right to "quote" the sources.

Comment: Thanks JB. I tend to err conservative on other people's work. The picture was well labeled as not reproducible without permission so I put in the link. Links do change and content moves or changes, so I will ask permission and then post the pic if approved. (I will also do more research on what I can do in referencing other sites beyond pointing at them)

Comment: How does that pipe cutter work? Looks interesting. Does it just go in a drill?

Comment: Yes, it goes on a drill and is typically used for access to pipes inside a wall or buried in concrete. I use a depth collar to ensure a square cut. The nice thing about the cutter is you can cut in very tight working spaces. The problem with the multi-tool in tight locations or larger pipes is you can't always get through the pipe because of blade length.

Answer (score 5):

I would not use the sawzall.  As you anticipate, it will vibrate the heck out of everything.  Hard to use for things not secure in place, and the back wall will just make the saw bounce.

Another alternative not mentioned yet is a "PVC Cable Saw", about $6.   A serrated wire you wrap around the stand pipe and pull back and forth.